# Finding $a,b$ for which a function is continuous and differentiable

Tags: derivatives, continuity, solution-verification

> Let
> $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
> ax + b, & \text{$x > 0$} \\
> 1 - x + x^2, & \text{ $x \leq 0$}.
> \end{cases} 
> $$
> a) Find all values of $a$ and $b$ for which the function is continuous.
> b) Find all values of $a$ and $b$ for which the function is differentiable.

Here is my attempt.

> (a) It suffices to find $a,b$ for which the left- and right-hand limits agree for $x = 0$. Indeed, polynomials are continuous, so for $x < 0$, $f(x)$ is continuous because $ax + b$ is continuous for any $a,b$. For $x > 0$, $f(x)$ is continuous because $1 - x + x^2$ is continuous. We need
> $$
> \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0) = 0 = 1. 
> $$
> The function is $1 - x + x^2$ for $x \geq 0$, and is hence right-continuous, so $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = f(0)$. For the function to be left-continuous, we need
> $$
> \lim\limits_{x \to 0^{-}} (ax + b) = 1.  
> $$
> Then, we have:
> \begin{align*}
> a \lim\limits_{x \to 0^{+}} x + \lim\limits b = a \cdot 0 + b = b = 1. 
> \end{align*}
> So $f$ is continuous for $b = 1$, any $a$.

> (b) For $x < 0$ and $x > 0$, we have differentiability because the polynomials $f(x)$ is defined as are differentiable, so it suffices to find $a,b$ for which $f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$. That is, we require
> $$ 
> (ax + b)' |_{x=0} = (1 - x + x^2)' |_{x=0}.
> $$
> Differentiating:
> $$ 
> a \mid_{x=0} = (-1 + 2x) |_{x=0}.
> $$
> Evaluating, we get $a = -1$. So $f$ is differentiable when $a = -1$, $b$ = anything.

Therefore, $f$ is continuous and differentiable when $a = -1$ and $b = 1$.

How does this look? Are the justifications correct?

EDIT: Am I correct that I don't need to use the limit definition, provided that I have access to derivative rules?

Comment: f can't be differentiable and discontinuous as differentiable => continuous

Comment: looks fine to me :) first take the derivative and look what the parameters should satisfy to glue them together and be differentiable. Than use the fact to check the continuous case!

Comment: $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ unless $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$. So if $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$ then $b $ cannot be "anything"

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Ok, so if I'm thinking of this correctly: differentiability implies continuity, but the converse isn't true. So in part (a), we can have $b = 1$, $a$ = anything to have continuity but not necessarily differentiability. In part (b), differentiability requires continuity, so I have to carry down continuity and require $b = 1$, $a = -1$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The sentence "So $f$ is differentiable when $a = -1$, $b$ = anything." is wrong. You already showed continuity implies $b=1$. On a test or assignment this would lose a mark.

Comment: I appreciate it. Thank you.